# How to get a Image from screen area

Tags: java, image-processing

I've made a aplication that draws a rectangle on the screen. I would like to get a image from the selected area from a position of the screen, Here's a example that shows what i'm looking:
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql1FK.png)

Draws a rectangle using mouse event which display the size of rectangle. wish get image from there, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the `Rectangle` to a `Robot` to capture the image as a `BufferedImage`:

```
import java.awt.Robot;

//usage:
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
```